Character mapping suddenly wrong
I have been using AutoHotKey to get special characters quickly for a few years. Recently I have noticed that my character mappings no longer work and is outputting various other things? Does anyone know why this may be? An update in Windows?
I am Using AutoHotKey 1.1 (I have not been able to succcessfully convert my .ahk to v2 yet).
Image
Tried updating to v2, but unsuccessful.

Perhaps posting your code rather than an image so other may try testing to see where the issue lies?
What is the expected result vs the actual result?

Yup, I tried using OCR, but it didn't help. It could never recognize the last character. Neither could I. Can you post your code?

Maybe try using it like this?
:X:flat::SendText "♭" ; This is for v2

Or like this?
:X:flat::SendText Chr(0x266D) ; This is also for v2

Why is it unsuccessful in updating to v2? Maybe there is some other part involved? The part you have given requires no additions or deletions.
If you are using v1.1, are you sure you're using the Unicode version? That can be the reason it is not working. But, for now, till you don't add the code as text, I can't help any more.
